# how do i join these two tables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables in SQL Server:

[image]

Now I want to write a select statement to join these 2 tables to get `MatchId`, `Host name` and `Guest name`.

What I tried:

```
select Match.Id, Team.Name, Team.Name 
from Match 
join Team on Match.HostId = Team.Id
```

and I got host name and guest name are the same.

```
select Match.Id, Team.Name, Team.Name 
from Match 
join Team on Match.HostId = Team.Id 
join Team on Match.GuestId = Team.Id
```

I got error.

Please help!

Comment: Please explain what you [have already tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) - we can help with that, but we will not write your code for you.

Comment: **WHAT error** did you get? We can't see your screen, nor can we read your mind - you need to **tell us** those relevant details ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will just need to join on the table twice:

```
select m.id MatchId, 
   h.name HostName, 
   g.name GuestName
from match m
left join team h
  on m.hostid = h.id
left join team g
  on m.guestid = g.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You will want to look at [simple joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for this:

```
SELECT m.Id AS MatchId, h.Name AS HostName, g.Name AS GuestName
FROM Match AS m
INNER JOIN Team AS h ON m.HostId = h.Id
INNER JOIN Team AS g ON m.GuestId = g.Id
```

You will need to join your Match table's HostId and GuestId separately  back to the Team table to get each individual team name.  I used aliases to prevent the error you saw in your second attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the ID is used to link records from both tables (i.e. though it's a primary key on both tables, it's also being used as a foreign key):

```
select m.HostId, m.GuestId, t.Name 
from Match m
left outer join Team t
    on m.id = t.id
```

If the ID isn't the same, you can do the following to match all teams to all matches:

```
select m.HostId, m.GuestId, t.Name 
from Match m
cross join Team t
```

If that's not what you're after, you may need to add a foreign key to one of the tables, or create a new table with a MatchId and a TeamId to link the two), then join on that

```
create table MatchTeam
(
    MatchId bigint not null
    ,TeamId bigint not null
)

go

select m.HostId, m.GuestId, t.Name 
from Match m
left outer join MatchTeam mt
    on m.Id = mt.MatchId
left outer join Team t
    on mt.TeamId = t.id
```

If hostid and guestid relate to the team table:

```
select m.id MatchId
, h.Name HostName
, g.Name GuestName 
from Match m
left outer join Team h
    on m.HostId = h.id
left outer join Team g
    on m.GuestId = h.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason  you are getting an error is because `Match` is a keyword in SQL hence you need either escape it using `'Match'` or by using a different name for your table.

I will just take Adam's query and modify it for your need:

```
SELECT m.Id AS MatchId, h.Name AS HostName, g.Name AS GuestName
FROM `Match` AS m
INNER JOIN Team AS h ON m.HostId = h.Id
INNER JOIN Team AS g ON m.GuestId = g.Id
```

Comment: The error the OP is receiving is due to a lack of aliasing the two INNER JOINs into Team.  I tested the table name of Match in SQL Server, and it works fine without `tick` marks.